# How do I troubleshoot when systemctl will not restart the sshd service?

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, sshd, systemctl

Long story short: I want to restart the `sshd` service because I think it might solve an issue I'm having using `ssh` on localhost.  **But I can't restart the `sshd` service**; this is the problem that I am asking for help with.  See the terminal output below.

I have been searching and trying any suggestion that seems like it could work for several hours today.  I have even restored my computer from a backup, twice.  Once to a point before the initial issue this morning.  That didn't help.  And once to a backup taken before I did anything with `ssh` configurations yesterday.  Even after restoring the system from that backup, I still can't restart the `sshd` service, and I can't use `ssh` on localhost.

The only "clue" I see in the journal log is the line stating `/etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied`.  But this seems to mean nothing.  The permissions for that file were 600.  I tried opening up the permissions all the way to 777.  Still, the same line of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied` is added to the journal logs.

**Please, if you know a different set of logs where I could find clues to this issue, please let me know.  If you have encountered this issue and solved it, please share.**

In case your advice is specific to a distro, my computer is running Fedora 37 at the moment.

**P.S.**  I tried running the command `/usr/sbin/sshd` on its own in the terminal.  From what I can tell, this is the same command that the service is meant to run.  When I run that command in the terminal, it works!  The command doesn't exit.  While it's running, I can use `ssh` without issue.  I need to use crtl+c to end the `/usr/sbin/sshd` command.  So why is the `sshd.service` job failing?

Below are sections of the relevant commands and their outputs:

```bash
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
Job for sshd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status sshd.service" and "journalctl -xeu sshd.service" for details.
```

```bash
$ systemctl status sshd.service
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-01-22 13:17:17 EST; 13s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 101315 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 101315 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 16ms
```

```bash
$ journalctl -xeu sshd.service
...
Jan 22 13:19:22 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
   Subject: A stop job for unit sshd.service has finished
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
   
   A stop job for unit sshd.service has finished.
   
   The job identifier is 11286 and the job result is done.

Jan 22 13:19:22 fedora systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
   Subject: A start job for unit sshd.service has begun execution
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
   
   A start job for unit sshd.service has begun execution.
   
   The job identifier is 11286.
Jan 22 13:19:22 fedora sshd[101395]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied
Jan 22 13:19:22 fedora systemd[1]: sshd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
   Subject: Unit process exited
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
   
   An ExecStart= process belonging to unit sshd.service has exited.
   
   The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jan 22 13:19:22 fedora systemd[1]: sshd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
   Subject: Unit failed
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
   
   The unit sshd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 22 13:19:22 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
   Subject: A start job for unit sshd.service has failed
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
   
   A start job for unit sshd.service has finished with a failure.
   
   The job identifier is 11286 and the job result is failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only "clue" I see in the journal log is the line stating /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied. But this seems to mean nothing.

It means your ssh can't start. Found your reason!

> But this seems to mean nothing. The permissions for that file were 600. I tried opening up the permissions all the way to 777

Don't do that, OpenSSH tends to block starting when some config files that shouldn't be are world-writable (for good reason; with 777, every user could have configured sshd to allow root login without checking any credentials).

The hint here is that this isn't happening, but that the SSH server still can't read the config file.

My bet here is that somehow (I never had that happen) the SELinux domain of the sshd.config got messed up.

```
 sudo fixfiles onboot
```

followed by a reboot should probably fix that.

Comment: Looks like it worked!  After running that command and rebooting:
```
$ systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-01-22 16:18:44 EST; 1min 58s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 4308 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18957)
     Memory: 2.2M
        CPU: 38ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
             └─4308 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll remember that command for later ;)  So much time wasted because I didn't know of this command and that an SELinux issue might be at play.  Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!